# unable to load SWT library on osx

Tags: java, swt, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having an error in intelliJ when trying to run on max osx snow leopard

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-win32-4234 in java.library.path
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /Users/bigbitecode/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-win32-4234.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/bigbitecode/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-win32.jnilib
```

The code works fine on windows and linux, but for some reason it fails to run after compiling on osx with the complaint above.

Something I find fishy is, "libswt-win32-*" Shouldn't it be using cocoa, since it's compiling on a mac? I checked the directory and sure enough there's nothing in the "../x86_64/" directory. 
However, I have already added the dependencies for the project to have swt.jar

Could it be that my JVM is set incorrectly?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Here's a manifest of my  swt.jar which is inside the lib folder

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SWT-OS: win32
SWT-WS: win32
SWT-Arch: x86_64
```

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that you are using the `swt.jar` for MacOS and don't reference the one for windows?

Comment: @Baz yes, in fact, I see lib-cocoa.jnilib and a few more Mac related  files inside the jar.

Comment: What does the manifest look like?

Comment: I found this inside the .jar of the SWT file:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.6.0_27-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SWT-OS: macosx
SWT-WS: cocoa
SWT-Arch:

Comment: Please add this to your question instead of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match your platforms of OS, VM, SWT.

for example:

OS: Windows 7 32bit
VM: JRE 7 win 32bit 
SWT: win32 binary

or,

OS: Windows 7 64bit
VM: JRE 7 win 64bit
SWT: win32_x64 binary

so, If your OS is OSX(mac), you should use SWT osx binary, not win32.